# Does a socket receive stream get closed when it receives a FIN packet?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to figure out how to implement a graceful disconnection (4-way handshake).

First I send a `FIN` packet using the following code:

```
shutdown(socket, SD_SEND);
```

This will cause the sending socket send stream to be closed. Now when the other side receives the `FIN` packet, it will also send it's `FIN` packet:

```
shutdown(socket, SD_SEND);
```

My question is: does receiving a `FIN` packet automatically closes a socket receive stream, and so there is no need to explicitly closing it:

```
shutdown(socket, SD_RECEIVE);
```

Comment: The normal graceful disconnection is to just close the socket completely. The TCP layer will handle the handshaking for you.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg `closesocket(socket);` will send an `RST` packet.

Comment: Read the documentation: [Graceful Shutdown, Linger Options, and Socket Closure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738547.aspx)

Comment: @user4572253 You might want to check a [state diagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Tcp_state_diagram_fixed_new.svg), `RST`is never sent during normal closing. In fact it's a *reset* signal used for exceptional events.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Wireshark always capture an `RST` packet when doing: `closesocket(socket);`. I have never seen it send a `FIN` packet.

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong, such as not reading all the pending data before you close. @JoachimPileborg is correct. And there is no such thing as a 'socket send stream' that is automatically closed, or a 'socket receive stream' that you can close. There is just the socket, and you should certainly close that. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: `closesocket(socket)` abruptly cleans up the socket resources. This should not send a RST but it also does not send an FIN or wait for the graceful shutdown. The RST seen in wireshark after a `closesocket(socket)` is likely in response to a packet arriving on the port that no longer has a socket associated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your question in parts:

You state:

> First I send a FIN packet using the following code:
>
> `shutdown(socket, SD_SEND)`
>
> This will cause the sending socket send stream to be closed. Now when the other
>   side receives the FIN packet, it will also send it's FIN packet:

First: The `shutdown(socket}` does not "close the send stream". It simply causes the socket to no longer accept `send()` calls. The send buffer is still there in the socket, you just can't put anything in it (because you said you wouldn't with the shutdown)

Second: You are correct that `shutdown(socket, SD_SEND)` should cause the socket to send a FIN. You are not correct that the other socket will send a FIN in response. The FIN your socket sends tells the other socket you will send no more data. The other socket may still have data it wants to send. The other socket will send a FIN when it also has no data to send. The other socket decides when to send a FIN.

To answer your actual question:

Receiving a FIN packet does not automatically "close a socket receive stream" as that is not something that can actually be done. The socket resources are only freed when `closesocket(socket)` is called. You can continue to call `recv()` even after a FIN has been received.